# How to import jQuery library files in existing application code using npm command

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm, knockout.js

Using a node JS `yo ko` command I have created a single-page application with Knockout-JS.

After that, I installed jquery packages. with the command `npm install jquery`

It is getting successfully installed. But now what I want to do is I want to use that jquery in my knockout.js Single page application. Is there any way or command by using which I can directly Import the Jquery library in required files?

Currently, files like Startup.js have the following code

```js
import ko from 'knockout';
import crossroads from 'crossroads';
import hasher from 'hasher';
```

And I want something like

```js
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'jquery-ui';
import ko from 'knockout';
import 'knockout-projections'
import 'knockout-postbox'
import 'jquery-hotkeys'
import 'bootstrap-wysiwyg'
import 'summernote'
import 'knockout-validation'
import 'jqueryNotific8'
import 'commanJs'
import 'moment'
import 'daterangePicker'
```

**Asking this for 2 reasons.**

1. Avoiding manual efforts of writing a code of import libraries
2. And I am not sure among all files wherever I want to add import and where exactly need to put all files of Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Jquery within your modules, you can use:

```js
import jquery from "jquery";
```

Or put whatever alias you want to hold the module's `default` export, as in:

```js
import $ from "jquery";
```

Same applies to all the other modules.

```js
import jquery from 'jquery';
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import jqueryUi from 'jquery-ui';
...
```

Comment: Thanks for this help. But I got my answer. I just went to the directory of my project and in that directory, I ran command of `npm install jquery` and all files automatically get updated with required jquery packets and imports.